# Convert "void*" to int without warning

Tags: c++

I need to convert "void*" to int, but compiler keeps giving me warning.
Wonder if there is a way to change the code so that compiler will not complain. This occurs a lot in the code base, especially when passing an argument to starting a new thread.

```
$ g++ -fpermissive te1.cc
te1.cc: In function ‘void dummy(void*)’:
te1.cc:4:15: warning: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
  int x = (int)p;
               ^
```

Here is the simple code "te1.cc":

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void someFunc(int);
void dummy(int type, void *p) {
    if (type == 0) {
        int x = (int)p;
        someFunc(x);
    } else if (type == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", (char*)p);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *p = (void*)5;
    dummy(p);
    return 0;
}
```

**UDPATE1**

I understand that I will lose precision. It's intended sometimes. What I need is to have a way to remove the warning in places I know for sure it's safe.  Sorry for not making it clear earlier.

**UDPATE2**

Updated the code snippet to be a little less non-trivial to illustrate the point. The parameter needs to pass different type of values. I need a way to cast without generating warning.

Comment: `static_cast<int>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(p))`. Note though that the cast does lose information - the compiler isn't warning you just for laughs. Why do you feel the need to cast - why don't you instead `printf("p = %p\n", p);` ?

Comment: You seems to be casting 64bit pointer to an int. try `#include <stdint.h> ... uintptr_t x = (uintptr_t)p`;

Comment: It complains because your pointer does not fit into an `int`. You should probably use `long long`, otherwise you'll lose half of the address.

Comment: Correction: `static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p))`

Comment: Why not `int p = 5; dummy(&p);` in `main()`, and then `void dummy(void *p) { int x = *(int *)p; printf("x = %d\n", x); }` for the function?  There's only one cast needed — that's an improvement.  You can use a reinterpret cast if you prefer that to the C style cast.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, it's meant as a simple example,  the point is that this function is so that caller can pass a pointer or an (4 byte) integer to callees.

Comment: The `printf` is simply an example. In reality, the callee will do something non-trivial with the passed in value. The passed in value should be intepreted as pointer in some cases or simply integer in some other cases.

Comment: So, did my suggestion not work for you? In what way does it fail to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, when I have `int x = static_cast<int>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(p));
 printf("x = %d\n",x);`,  I got compile error `te1.cc: In function ‘void dummy(void*)’:
te1.cc:6:51: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘uintptr_t {aka long unsigned int}’
  int x = static_cast<int>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(p));
                                                   ^
`  Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: I did post a correction (4th comment).

Comment: all of your code looks like `C` to me. Are you sure you want to tag this as `C++`?

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik, your correction did it.  This C++ trick works great.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, do you want to change the comment into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for something along the lines of

```
int x = static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p));
```

This is not strictly guaranteed to work: perhaps surprisingly, the standard guarantees that a pointer converted to a large enough integer and back to a pointer results in the same value; but doesn't provide a similar guarantee for when an integer is converted to a pointer and back to the integer. All it says about the latter case is

> **[expr.reinterpret.cast]/4** A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined. [ *Note:* It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine. *—end note* ]

Hopefully, you know the addressing structure of your machine, and won't be surprised.

Answer (score 7):

> I need to convert "void*" to int

no you don't.

> I really do...

no, you need to represent a pointer as some kind of integer type which is guaranteed not to lose information.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <cinttypes>

void dummy(void *p) {
    std::intptr_t x = reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(p);
    printf("x = %" PRIiPTR "\n", x);
// ^^ see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *p = (void*)5;
    dummy(p);
    return 0;
}
```

> ok, what I really want to do is work with 32-bit values in a standards-compliant way.

This is what `std::uint32_t` is for:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

void dummy(std::uint32_t x) {
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto x = std::uint32_t(5);
    dummy(x);
    return 0;
}
```

`std::uint32_t` - guaranteed to be unsigned 32 bits

`std::int32_t` - guaranteed to be signed 32 bits

Comment: Thanks @richard-hodges for the answer. Sometimes I just need to pass in an 4-byte integer. How can I receive this integer in the callee without causing a warning?

Comment: @packetie std::uint32_t is a standardised unsigned 32 bit integer. It is not a pointer. Void* is a pointer, which on my laptop is 64 bits.